# Problem with Firefox "manifest" file

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, manifest, firefox3.6

I was trying out [this XUL tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial) on Firefox 3.6.13.

The example extension in the tutorial is meant to find files. This is my `manifest` file:

```
content findfile file:///home/darthshak/Programs/firefox/findfile/content/
skin findfile classic/1.0 file:///home/darthshak/Programs/firefox/findfile/skin/
locale findfile en-US file:///home/darthshak/Programs/firefox/findfile/locale/
```

This file is located at `/usr/lib/firefox-3.6.13/chrome` and is called `findfile.manifest`.

In `/home/darthshak/Programs/firefox/findfile/content/findfile.xul` I have put this sample XUL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="findfile-window" title="Find files" orient="horizontal"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <button id="find-button" label="Find"/>
    <button id="cancel-button" label="Cancel"/>
</window>
```

Now, the darn thing never runs when I execute the following command:

```
firefox -chrome chrome://findfile/content/findfile.xul
```

Only a PID is output on the terminal, and nothing appears.

I downloaded the `ChromeList` extension, and to my chagrin, I found the following directory structure:

```
findfile/
    content/
        content/
            findfile.xul
        skin/
        locale/
    skin/
        content/
            findfile.xul
        skin/
        locale/
    locale/
        content/
            findfile.xul
        skin/
        locale/
```

Further, when I launched `findfile.xul` with the option "Open in new window", nothing appeared. However, it worked only when I chose "Open in new tab" or "Launch".

I tried a lot of things (except, obviously, the right thing which would have solved this problem) which included renaming the `.xul` file, changing the `findfile.manifest` file and so on. Oddly, when I added the manifest file in the `chrome` directory in `/home/darthshak/.mozilla/`, the manifest did not even register on `ChromeList`.

Comment: did you try perhaps: chrome://findfile/content/content/findfile.xul  ? Btw, I don't think the way you're doing it is the best for your testing. Actually it's pretty bad because you cannot package your extension and install it in Firefox. Try the above chrome link, and I'll give you more details on what to do. It would be good to add folder structure of your extension on disk (it will be possibly different from what ChromeList shows)

Comment: Yeah - that tutorial page doesn't work for me either. I try launching firefox with the -chrome argument but nothing appears.

Comment: I am assuming that Firefox won't read XUL files from the filesystem for security purposes. You need to package the extension for Firefox to read it.

Comment: Hi, still do u have this problem. I would like to propose a solution for this problem.

Comment: @darthshak: could you please tell me about development environment?